# "android list target" show nothing for AOSP build

Tags: android, build, android-source

According instructions listed in http://source.android.com/source/building.html, a full build can be build, and the emulator can be started OK.

Android 4.0.4 source codes is downloaded and built.

`. build/envsetup.sh`

`lunch full-eng`

`make`

```
root@computer0OfGod:~/customEmulator# android list target
Available Android targets:
```

But run `android list target` show nothing, so avd can not be created.

Expected result is that there should be at least one target be listed.
How can I bring the target out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but I think you need to create your avd first:

```
$ ./android create avd -n [Your AVD's name] -t 1
```

for reference: http://blog.sheikhaman.com/2010/10/android-os-source-code-modification_13.html

I hope it will be helpful !

Comment: the problem is that "-t 1" specify the target 1.   In my scenario, there are no target being listed, which means there are 0 targets.   So "-t 1" is not valid.

Comment: Got it. the link is very helpful. My problem is that I used /root/customEmulator/out/host/linux-x86/bin/emulator. instead the /customEmulator/out/host/linux-x86/sdk/android-sdk_eng.root_linux-x86/tools/emulator should be used. I am wondering if there is any difference between these 2.

Comment: I'm glad to help you.sorry!I don't know the exact difference between them.by the way,I'm wondering about one thing,Is it possible to modify android source code via eclipse on Windows OS.I will be grateful if you can help.

Comment: I am not clear of you question. 1.Eclipse editor of course can modify any codes, including android source code, maybe this is not what u want.   2. Or maybe what u want is to start android emulator(from AOSP) from eclipse? In this case, we may replace the google's sdk emulator with our own build emulator.

Comment: Ok let me make it simple.I want to modify android source code but I don't have mac or linux.Is it possible with Windows OS ?

Comment: of course it can be done. just install eclipse for windows. download it from here: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.2.1-201209141800/eclipse-SDK-4.2.1-win32-x86_64.zip

Comment: brother,m an android app developer.actually from the official documents I found that it can't be done using windows.thats why I asked for working around this limitation.this was the document from I found the limitation.look at first 2 lines of this document: http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html

Comment: ah... I assume modification to be "editing codes". Sorry for my not completely catch your meaning