# Why is my command line android list targets showing nothing?

Tags: android, sdk, android-ndk

I'm running windows 10 with Android Studios installed but I'm doing all this from the command line.  I downloaded the latest android sdk.  then i downloaded project files from [github](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two).

I ran a build ndk-build.  i assume it is successful because it took about 20 minutes or so.  In a sub folder `libs/mips` where files were generated: `liblept.so`, `libpng.so`, and `libtess.so`.

Then I tried to run an android update project command like this:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools>android update project -p c:\tess\tess-two`

I made sure that inside the tess-two folder there is `AndroidManifest.xml`.

I get this error message:

```
Error: The project either has no target set or the target is invalid.
Please provide a --target to the 'android.bat update' command.
```

After researching the Android Development page I ran this command :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools>android list targets
```

the result was just a single line with no lists if targets like this without an error message or anything:

Available Android targets:

How can i get the project to update as the example I'm trying to follow [here](http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/#comment-184181) suggests.

I tried solution found here ["android list target" show nothing for AOSP build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372742/android-list-target-show-nothing-for-aosp-build) ...but got error message that i needed a target id before I could build an AVD.

I tried some random target IDas but they were not valid..What am i doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: NEW INFO
Thanks for helping, I got the list by using: "android list" instead of "android target list".  Must be a windows version; I just upgraded to Windows 10.

So here's what I got.  The thing is how do I know which target id to use?  In my AndroidManifest.xml file I see this attribute:

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" />
```

I have three folders: "armeabi-v7a","mips","x860".  Each folder has three files:  "liblept.so","libpng.so","libtess.so".  Is the list of targets that I found related to the targetSdkVersion or any of the three library files?

I'm not sure which one to use with android update project --path . --target.

Here's the list that was found:

C:\android-sdk\android-sdk-windows\platforms>android list
Available Android targets:
Available Android Virtual Devices:

The following Android Virtual Devices could not be loaded:
    Name: Nexus_5_API_22_x86
    Path: C:\Users....android\avd\Nexus_5_API_22_x86.avd
   Error: Unknown target 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:22' in C:\Users....android
\avd\Nexus_5_API_22_x86.ini
Available devices definitions:
id: 0 or "tv_1080p"
    Name: Android TV (1080p)
    OEM : Google

### Tag : android-tv

id: 1 or "tv_720p"
    Name: Android TV (720p)
    OEM : Google

### Tag : android-tv

id: 2 or "wear_round"
    Name: Android Wear Round
    OEM : Google

### Tag : android-wear

id: 3 or "wear_square"
    Name: Android Wear Square
    OEM : Google

### Tag : android-wear

id: 4 or "Galaxy Nexus"
    Name: Galaxy Nexus

### OEM : Google

id: 5 or "Nexus 10"
    Name: Nexus 10

### OEM : Google

id: 6 or "Nexus 4"
    Name: Nexus 4

### OEM : Google

id: 7 or "Nexus 5"
    Name: Nexus 5

### OEM : Google

id: 8 or "Nexus 6"
    Name: Nexus 6

### OEM : Google

id: 9 or "Nexus 7 2013"
    Name: Nexus 7

### OEM : Google

id: 10 or "Nexus 7"
    Name: Nexus 7 (2012)

### OEM : Google

id: 11 or "Nexus 9"
    Name: Nexus 9

### OEM : Google

id: 12 or "Nexus One"
    Name: Nexus One

### OEM : Google

id: 13 or "Nexus S"
    Name: Nexus S

### OEM : Google

id: 14 or "2.7in QVGA"
    Name: 2.7" QVGA

### OEM : Generic

id: 15 or "2.7in QVGA slider"
    Name: 2.7" QVGA slider

### OEM : Generic

id: 16 or "3.2in HVGA slider (ADP1)"
    Name: 3.2" HVGA slider (ADP1)

### OEM : Generic

id: 17 or "3.2in QVGA (ADP2)"
    Name: 3.2" QVGA (ADP2)

### OEM : Generic

id: 18 or "3.3in WQVGA"
    Name: 3.3" WQVGA

### OEM : Generic

id: 19 or "3.4in WQVGA"
    Name: 3.4" WQVGA

### OEM : Generic

id: 20 or "3.7 FWVGA slider"
    Name: 3.7" FWVGA slider

### OEM : Generic

id: 21 or "3.7in WVGA (Nexus One)"
    Name: 3.7" WVGA (Nexus One)

### OEM : Generic

id: 22 or "4in WVGA (Nexus S)"
    Name: 4" WVGA (Nexus S)

### OEM : Generic

id: 23 or "4.65in 720p (Galaxy Nexus)"
    Name: 4.65" 720p (Galaxy Nexus)

### OEM : Generic

id: 24 or "4.7in WXGA"
    Name: 4.7" WXGA

### OEM : Generic

id: 25 or "5.1in WVGA"
    Name: 5.1" WVGA

### OEM : Generic

id: 26 or "5.4in FWVGA"
    Name: 5.4" FWVGA

### OEM : Generic

id: 27 or "7in WSVGA (Tablet)"
    Name: 7" WSVGA (Tablet)

### OEM : Generic

id: 28 or "10.1in WXGA (Tablet)"
    Name: 10.1" WXGA (Tablet)
    OEM : Generic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure that you have at least one target available for use, navigate to your `sdk/installation/path/platforms` and see if you have any version of android in there.

This is the output I get with `android list targets`:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
Available Android targets:
----------
id: 1 or "android-19"
     Name: Android 4.4.2
     Type: Platform
     API level: 19
     Revision: 4
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
 Tag/ABIs : default/armeabi-v7a
----------
id: 2 or "android-22"
     Name: Android 5.1.1
     Type: Platform
     API level: 22
     Revision: 2
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
 Tag/ABIs : android-tv/armeabi-v7a, android-tv/x86, default/armeabi-v7a, default/x86, default/x86_64
----------
id: 3 or "android-23"
     Name: Android 6.0
     Type: Platform
     API level: 23
     Revision: 1
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
 Tag/ABIs : default/armeabi-v7a, default/x86, default/x86_64
----------
id: 4 or "Google Inc.:Google APIs (x86 System Image):19"
     Name: Google APIs (x86 System Image)
     Type: Add-On
     Vendor: Google Inc.
     Revision: 15
     Description: Android x86 + Google APIs
     Based on Android 4.4.2 (API level 19)
     Libraries:
      * com.android.future.usb.accessory (usb.jar)
          API for USB Accessories
      * com.google.android.media.effects (effects.jar)
          Collection of video effects
      * com.google.android.maps (maps.jar)
          API for Google Maps
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
 Tag/ABIs : default/x86
----------
id: 5 or "Google Inc.:Google APIs:22"
     Name: Google APIs
     Type: Add-On
     Vendor: Google Inc.
     Revision: 1
     Description: Android + Google APIs
     Based on Android 5.1.1 (API level 22)
     Libraries:
      * com.android.future.usb.accessory (usb.jar)
          API for USB Accessories
      * com.google.android.media.effects (effects.jar)
          Collection of video effects
      * com.google.android.maps (maps.jar)
          API for Google Maps
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
 Tag/ABIs : google_apis/armeabi-v7a, google_apis/x86, google_apis/x86_64
```

I see you are building `tess-two`, so this is the command I used when I got to that part:

`android update project --path . --target 3`

Note I used `.` as the path because I was already in the `tess-two` folder and `.` in linux represents the current folder.

Comment: Hi I did get the list thanks.  You did answer my question but I wonder if I could also ask...how do I know which target id to use with "android update project --path . --target"?  I added the list that I found to my original question.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: The list you have does not list any valid targets. You have simply listed the AVD's installed. The target id to use is the latest version of Android your app supports. In my case I want to target the latest which is Android M (Api 23) which is why I used target 3 or `android-23`(as shown in the output above)

Comment: Tried your solutions on Windows 7.  They work.  I guess I'm going to download jdk's again on my Windows 10 machine.  Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to run SDK Manager and Update and Install all of the default packages:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\SDK Manager.exe`